# S3 pre-signed url keeps return provided token has expired after after sometime of service deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I have this code for sign s3 urls

```
private URL generatePreSignedUrl(String s3Key, String s3Bucket, Date expiration, HttpMethod method) {
        GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(s3Bucket, s3Key)
                .withMethod(method)
                .withExpiration(expiration);
        return amazonS3.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
    }
```

and these properties

```
spring:
 cloud:
    aws:
      credentials:
        sts:
          web-identity-token-file: /var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount/token

cloud:
  aws:
    region:
       static: us-east-1
    stack:
      auto: false
    credentials:
      use-default-aws-credentials-chain: true
```

the function works fine after the service is deployed, but after some time keeps fail with provided token expired
I'm using springboot 3
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4nl9.png)

it should works fine and sign the urls, but it fail after some time

Answer (score 0):

The AWS S3 presigned url has an expiration time (check the link parameters).  By default it is 900 seconds (15 min). You can set the expiration timestamp explicitly `.setExpiration(Date timestamp)` however at most for 7 days. That is valid for long term credentials.

Using temporary session credentials (e.g. the runtime role for EC2 or container), the signature expires when the session-generated access key expires. By default every hour (as far I know, I may be wrong).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use.html#id_roles_use_view-role-max-session

> You can use this parameter to specify the duration of the role session, from 900 seconds (15 minutes) up to the maximum session duration setting for the role. Before you specify the parameter, you should view this setting for your role. If you specify a value for the DurationSeconds parameter that is higher than the maximum setting, the operation fails.

If some reasonable long duration is needed, the application can call AssumeRole, where it is possible to specify duration  from 1 hour to 12 hours.